# Property 'length' does not exist on type 'NumberSchema<number>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, yup

i am getting error which one mention in title.i know what error is but don't get it how to solve it.

basically i am using 'Yup' for validation.

added custom method

```
Yup.addMethod(Yup.number, 'length', function (length: number, message: string) {
  const tmessage = (typeof message == 'undefined') ? 'length must be ' + length : message;
    return Yup.number().test('length',tmessage,function(value: string | number) {
      return (typeof value == 'undefined') ? true : (value.toString().length === this.resolve(length));
    });
});
```

define validation schema

```
const validationSchema = Yup.object({
  name: Yup.string().required('Name is required'),
  email: Yup.string().email('Invalid Email').required('Email id required'),
  mobile: Yup.number().required('Mobile is required').length(10),
  message: Yup.string().required('Message is required')
});
```

i am getting typescript error on line

```
mobile: Yup.number().required('Mobile is required').length(10),
```

Answer (score 3):

You can augment type definitions for the module like described in https://github.com/jquense/yup/issues/312#issuecomment-422666195 . In your case, create any `.d.ts` file in your project and insert this:

```
declare module "yup" {
    interface NumberSchema<T extends number | null | undefined = number> {
        length(length: number, message: string): NumberSchema<T>;
    }
}
```

Or not ideal but simple solution: disable type checking by using `(Yup as any).number().required('Mobile is required').length(10)`.